# How selenium grid 2 works?

Tags: java, excel, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I'm working on a keyword driven framework which has data written in excel sheet.
Each row represents a test case.Initally, table containing data is read . How do i give each row to selenium parallely. I would like to know , how to run the rows of excel sheet parallely. How to make selenium grid work parallely ,for a framework without junit and testng

Comment: Can you specify why it should be without Junit and testng?

Comment: Our framework is designed in such a way that it has only one java class which will run the entire suite.framework doesn't use junit nor testng.Is there a way , we can integrate junit/testNG to our java classes.Our test cases are written in xml.

Comment: Does your framework these XML files and then execute the test? Is there one method which does this? If the execution is always happening from a method in framework, then you can use testNG to ru trigger tests in parallel. You will have to use one these framework or atleast ant to run the tests in parallel. If you use testng or junit it has many more features which will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't use TestNG or jUnit, you'll need to just use your own mulithreaded runner.  That's going to be considerably more difficult, but it's certainly doable.  That's all these other tools would do under the covers for you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

TestNG is best option for such tests. You can read more about `@DataProvider` attribute. And you have to add Attribute parallel="tests" in you TestNG.xml,too to run Tests in parallel.

Comment: But, we are not using testng in our framework.How can i bring in the concept of parallelism without testnG.